# CSS svg background covers div content

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to add waves for one of the divs. I used some website that generated svg with neccessary code. The problem is it covers all the content of my div. What seems to be the problem here?

```css
  .Upper-half-wrapper {
      background-color: #0A2640;
      height: 515px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .custom-shape-divider-top-1655888002 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
    }
    
    .custom-shape-divider-top-1655888002 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 266px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    .custom-shape-divider-top-1655888002 .shape-fill {
      fill: #1B3B5D;
    }
```

```html
 <div className="Upper-half-wrapper">
            <div className="custom-shape-divider-top-1655888002">
              <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path
                  d="M0,0V46.29c47.79,22.2,103.59,32.17,158,28,70.36-5.37,136.33-33.31,206.8-37.5C438.64,32.43,512.34,53.67,583,72.05c69.27,18,138.3,24.88,209.4,13.08,36.15-6,69.85-17.84,104.45-29.34C989.49,25,1113-14.29,1200,52.47V0Z"
                  opacity=".25" className="shape-fill"></path>
                <path
                  d="M0,0V15.81C13,36.92,27.64,56.86,47.69,72.05,99.41,111.27,165,111,224.58,91.58c31.15-10.15,60.09-26.07,89.67-39.8,40.92-19,84.73-46,130.83-49.67,36.26-2.85,70.9,9.42,98.6,31.56,31.77,25.39,62.32,62,103.63,73,40.44,10.79,81.35-6.69,119.13-24.28s75.16-39,116.92-43.05c59.73-5.85,113.28,22.88,168.9,38.84,30.2,8.66,59,6.17,87.09-7.5,22.43-10.89,48-26.93,60.65-49.24V0Z"
                  opacity=".5" className="shape-fill"></path>
                <path
                  d="M0,0V5.63C149.93,59,314.09,71.32,475.83,42.57c43-7.64,84.23-20.12,127.61-26.46,59-8.63,112.48,12.24,165.56,35.4C827.93,77.22,886,95.24,951.2,90c86.53-7,172.46-45.71,248.8-84.81V0Z"
                  className="shape-fill"></path>
              </svg>
           </div>
           <div className="Upper-half-content">
             Some text
           </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is not a background image

Comment: @Paulie_D it's a svg that acts as a background. What do you mean?

Comment: It is a svg, a normal image. A background image is set in CSS via `background-image` . (You can even use SVG there) In your case there is no background image.

Comment: @cloned so I can achieve the same with `background-image` property?

Comment: If it is a background-image then you should use background-image property from CSS. You can achieve your desired effect using it, I am sure. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ read this, especially the section about using data-urls for background-value

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer was to use `position: relative;` on content i wanted to be on top.